API cookies not working with Vercel and SSR pages
I having been dealing with this issue for days and can't seem to get around it. Is there really no way to access cookies within an API when handling SSR requests with Vercel? That's the big kicker here, this works locally but does NOT work when deployed to Vercel.
I've tried calling fetch with credentials "include" and setting the Cookie header. const token within my API is always null when it should contain my session cookie info.
I've even tried grabbing the session from the req object and that works but again, only locally and not on Vercel.
My SSR Page:
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const fetchOrder = async (params) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(process.env.URL + '/api/orders/' + params.orderId, {

                credentials: 'include', //I've tried this
                headers: { 
                    Cookie: cookies().toString(), //and I've tried this
                }
            }
        );
        const order = await response.json();

        //redirect to 404 if not found
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Failed to fetch order');
        }

        return order;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching order:', error);
    }
};

Here is my API route:
import 'server-only';

import { connectToDB } from '@utils/database';
import { getSession } from '@utils/server/auth';

//api/orders/[orderId]
export const GET = async (req, { params }) => {
    try {
        const token = await getSession(); //ALWAYS NULL WHEN DEPLOYED TO VERCEL
        await connectToDB();

    }

Get Session function:
export async function getSession() {
    const cookie = cookies().get('session')?.value;
    const session = await decrypt(cookie);

    if (!session?.id) {
        return { isAuth: null, id: null };
    }

    //renew session
    const expiresAt = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
    const newSession = await encrypt({ id: session.id, expiresAt });

    cookies().set('session', newSession, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        expires: expiresAt,
        sameSite: 'Lax',
        path: '/',
    });

    return { isAuth: true, id: session.id };
}


A few thoughts: Vercel is unlikely to be a variable here. You may want to check the behavior of *.vercel.app and if its playing a part here (check Public Suffix List).
